# C++ link OpenCV library from project folder

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code, compilation, portability

So, I've got two computers on computer A I've installed OpenCV and wrote a program that uses the library. On second computer (B) I want to run and ideally compile the program without having to install OpenCV library.

my folder structure is:

```
Program
|-- Main.h
|-- Main.cpp
|-- Driver.h
|-- ...
|-- opencv2
|   |-- aruco
|   |-- bioinspired
|   |-- ...
|   |-- ...
|   |-- core.hpp
|   |-- ...
```

And I'm including opencv in my program like this:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
```

Since I'm working in **VS Code** I have tasks.json:

```
/* tasks.json */
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "clang++",
            "args": [

                "-std=c++17",
                "-o",
                "Main", // executable
                "Main.cpp", // main file
                "Driver.cpp",
                "DetectRegions.cpp",
                "Plate.cpp",
                "-g",
                "-v",
                "-debug",
                "$(pkg-config", //here I see biggest problem
                "--cflags", 
                "--libs", 
                "opencv4)"      //as well as here

            ],
            "type": "shell",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "shared"
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Well those are args I found on the internet that worked for someone else. It compiles on computer B but I'm pretty sure it's reason why it doesn't work on computer B. Because I'm linking installed OpenCV library, not the one that is in my program folder.

But if I try to rewrite "args" to something like this, it doesn't work.

```
            "args": [

                "-std=c++17",
                "-o",
                "Main", // executable
                "Main.cpp", // main file
                "Driver.cpp",
                "DetectRegions.cpp",
                "Plate.cpp",
                "-g",
                "-v",
                "-debug",
                "$(", 
                "--cflags", 
                "--libs", 
                "./opencv2)"

            ],
```

Could you guys please help me with this and point me into correct dirrection on how to make my program portable and compilable just using the "opencv2" folder that I'm carriing with all the header and cpp files?

Thank you!
Regards
Michal